# Android - ImageView of Group in ExpandableListView Blinks on GroupSelect

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-glide

So I'm using custom view for the GroupView of `ExpandableListView` like this :

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_shop_header, null);
    }

    ImageView groupIndicator = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_shop_header_indicator);
    groupIndicator.setSelected(isExpanded);

    CircularImageView vendorAvatar = (CircularImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_shop_header_avatar);

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(Constants.WEB_ADDRESS +
                    sharedPreferenceUtilities.getValue(context,
                            sharedPreferencesList.loginSharedPreference,
                            sharedPreferencesList.vendorAvatarString))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .dontAnimate()
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(vendorAvatar);

    OpenSansFont listHeader = (OpenSansFont) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.drawer_shop_header_title);
    listHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}
```

As can be seen, I am using Glide to download the image from server. The problem is, it blink on group press. So whenever the `ExpandableListView` is either expanded or collapses, the ImageView gets blink-ed..

Is this because of Glide? If yes, what to do here?

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @Expiredmind No I haven't hahaha.. It is actually the default behavior of Glide to fade in a newly loaded image and I don't know how to override the method of `ExpListV` to not load new view each time it is expanded or collapsed.. There should be something to do with `if ImageView is not empty, then dont load`..